# how should I divide a network into several smaller vlans on a extreme switch?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, subnet, iproute

I get a C-network from my ISP, and there's a static route in ISP side pointing to one ipaddress(192.168.0.2) in my C-network so that this C-net can be reached from outside world. I use a Extreme X460 switch to connect to my ISP, it works fine when I define the C-net on my switch.

Now I'm trying to break the C-net into several smaller subnet, with different vlan. problem start to pop.

I made 2 /29 networks, the topology looks like below:

[image]

Now the servers in vlan 100 still works fine, I can ping 192.168.0.2 and other servers in this vlan from "internet"

But the vlan 200 can not be accessed from "Internet" or ISP switch, on my switch I can ping 192.168.0.17 and other servers from 192.168.0.2, but from 192.168.0.17 I can not ping 192.168.0.1 or "Internet".

I enabled ipforwarding on both vlan100 and vlan200, the "show iproute" give result like in the picture.

Is there any logic mistake in this design?

Answer (score 1):

You're using /24 on one switch and /28 on the other. That means 192.168.0.1 thinks 192.168.0.17 is in the same subnet, it is not. You'll need to route between the networks.